# risk of entering group level predictors in regression to predict individual outcomes?

Tags: multiple-regression

My GOAL: I have been running a multivariate linear regression analysis to predict student outcomes (grades; measured at the individual student level) from several variables measures at the student level (age, gender, and a few others), and also from 2 self-report teacher variables (teacher stress, teaching experience). I have 10 classrooms and 250 kids; so the teacher variables (stress, and teaching experience) have a true N of 10; however, because the data is merged, each student within one classroom is associated with the same teacher value for stress and the same value for experience. I know that ideally, I would conduct this analysis as a nested model and enter the student variables as Level 1 variables and the Teacher variables as Level 2 variables. However, with 10 classrooms only, I don't have enough power to do that. Now, if I conduct this as a regular multiple regression, am I getting totally biased results? I am trying to understand this before going ahead.

Comment: Have you tried clustering the errors on teacher? Section VI of [Cameron and Miller's 2014 JHR paper](http://cameron.econ.ucdavis.edu/research/Cameron_Miller_JHR_2014_July_09.pdf#Page=23) discussed some of the finite sample adjustments you can make. Also see example 1 on page 5 for a very relevant example.